# jquery Dialog display it content on load on the screen

Tags: jquery, dialog

hi friend  i am trying to create custom dialog using j-query and inside dialog i am  putting some text box and check box , but the problem is when  i am displaying dialog box on button click , only the content inside the dialog will display onload and when i click on buttton it will appear in dialog only that too only first time only, what i want is it only display in dialog not onload ,and i dont want to make all component hide/show  display none/block every time ,because i have many component in dialog.

here is my code

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="/resources/demos/external/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <script>
    /*$(document).ready(function (){
        $('#dialog').append('<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">dfhgdfg</input>');
    });*/
    function call(){
    $(function() {
        $("#dialog").dialog();
        $('p').css({'display':'block'});
    });
}
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p style="display:none;">This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">test1</input>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">test2</input>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">test3</input>

</div>
 <input type="button" onclick="call();" value="button"></input>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle for this?

Answer (score 2):

Nest you `#dialog` div in another div with style `display: none`. Then initialize the dialog plugin on the `#dialog` div.

```
<div style="display: none">
  <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p style="display:none;">This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">test1</input>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">test2</input>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">test3</input>

  </div>
</div>
```

Then, change your jQuery code to the following:

```
$(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog();
    $('p').css({'display':'block'});
    $('input[type="button"]').on('click', function(){
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    })
    .click();  //Since you also want it to open once on page load
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this:

```
$(document).ready(function (){      
    $("#dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal: true });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p style="display:none;">This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">test1</input>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">test2</input>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">test3</input>
</div>

<button type="button" id="open-dialog">Open</input>

<script> <!-- Put in header or footer -->
    var $Dialog = $('#dialog');
    $Dialog.css('display', 'none').dialog('close');
    $('#open-dialog').on('click', function(){
        $Dialog.dialog();
    })
</script>
```